# Can't compare dates in Angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, date

I have 2 dates that I need to do some logic. The first date comes from SQL database and the second date is the current date that from angular. 
I would like to display them in an HTML table if the SQL date is earlier, apply css style`behind` and later, apply `ahead` css style.

my current date that I use in `component.ts` is:

```
today: any = Date.now();
```

And my HTML table that I use `ngIf` is:

```
<td *ngIf="p.serverDate >= today" class="ahead">{{ p.serverDate | date }}</td>
<td *ngIf="p.serverDate < today" class="behind">{{ p.serverDate | date }}</td>
```

`p` is the object that returned from database that has date in it. I am ppretty sure that I have the `serverDate` and `today`. I can use `date` pipe on both of them. Why can't I use the simple if statement in here?

UPDATE: I've just found out that
`serverDate` is `2018-07-24T20:34:48` and `today` is `1533235371115` format.

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't use`? Do you get an error? Or none of the `<td>`gets displayed?

Comment: Did you try with `+p.serverDate >= +today` or `p.serverDate.getTime() >= today.getTime()` you need to compare the milliseconds for "=" otherwise it will return wrong result.

Comment: In my current settings, there is no comperation going on. Basically, `td` has nothing. I used `+` and `getTime()` and I received that `getTime()` is not a function

Comment: something you can do to help debug is `*ngIf="compareFn(p.server, today)"` and then do something like `compareFn(s, t){ console.log(s, t, s < t)}` in the component

Comment: @GoGO did you try to replace `server` with `serverDate`? If so, please update the question to correct the typo.

Comment: It was typo. Also, I add date formats in the post

Comment: That's your problem, you can't compare two different types like that - both comparisons will return false.  You need to convert both values to date objects or numbers.

Comment: Found a solution: I was comparing wrong data types. So, I needed to make sure they're the same data type. What I did was convert `today` as date object. `today = new Date().toJSON();`.

Comment: @GoGo Careful with that, if they're both strings then there's no guarantee you'll get an accurate comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be date from MySQL DB might be in string. You need to convert using new Date().
For any date manipulation, you can check moment.js library or date-fns library. For comparison b/w dates use isBefore() method in https://momentjs.com/docs/.